# How to find out when all addresses have been geocoded

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In the Google Maps API, multiple calls to `google.maps.ClientGeocoder.getLatLng(address, callback)` are not guaranteed to finish in any order. What is an elegant way to determine all addresses have been geocoded, given an array of addresses?

Should I just count down based on the length of the array and execute code in the callback only if the countdown reaches zero, or is there a better way to do this in the Google Maps API?

Thanks

Comment: I use the workflow you described.  It works fine and is elegant enough for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not doing special case processing for each lat lng response (ie just doing something when they have all come back), I don't see a downside with your counting down solution.